# With javascript how can I identify the HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, dom

I had another question similar to this but the answers seemed to miss out that I was trying to find the `<HTML>` tag and modify it.

They suggested:

```
elem.className = elem.className.replace(/\blight\b/," dark ");
```

But with javascript how can I get the `<HTML>` tag as the elem variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get `<html>` tag you could just do:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
```

or

```
var elem = document.querySelector("html");
```

or

```
var elem = document.body.parentNode;
```

Comment: Perfect !  What about the suggestion above document.querySelector('html') is that also valid? I have not seen that before.

Comment: Yes it is valid in "modern" browsers.

Comment: @Marilou: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector.

Answer (score 1):

The following code returns the html element

```
document.documentElement
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlTag = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]
```